# Why am I getting "Non-exhaustive patterns in function..." when I invoke my Haskell substring function?

Tags: haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm working my way through the book [The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0954300696).  (I'm only mid-way through chapter 1, but I'm enjoying it so far and intend to continue.)  I've read through the section 1.5 "Playing the Haskell Game" which "consists of a number of further examples to get you acquainted with [Haskell]".  So far I've learned about functions, type declarations, guarded equations, a little about list pattern matching, and where & let.

I'm stuck on exercise 1.17, which asks us to write a function substring :: String -> String -> Bool where:

1. if xs is a prefix of ys, xs is a substring of ys
2. if ys equals y:ys' and xs is a substring of ys', xs is a substring of ys
3. nothing else is a substring of ys

I used the prefix function provided in a previous example:

```
prefix :: String -> String -> Bool
prefix [] ys = True
prefix (x:xs) [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x==y) && prefix xs ys
```

And then tried:

```
substring :: String -> String -> Bool
subsstring xs [] = False
substring xs (y:ys) | prefix xs (y:ys) = True
                    | substring xs ys  = True
                    | otherwise        = False
```

...and may other permutations of this.

When I run `substring "abc" "xxxabcyyy"` I get `True`, but when I run `substring "abc" "xxxabyyy"` I get "*** Exception: substring.hs:(3,0)-(5,45): Non-exhaustive patterns in function substring".  I can't figure out why.  I don't understand how there could be non-exhaustive patterns when I use "otherwise".

BTW, the book has not yet covered if-then-else.  I'd prefer to keep that out of my solution, for now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a typo in the function name:

```
subsstring xs [] = False
```

Because of the typo this declares a new function `subsstring`, not a case of the `substring` function.

The `substring` function itself then doesn't have any case that would match a second parameter of `[]`.

Comment: I can't decide whether to be embarrassed that I wasted your time with a typo, or pleased that my solution worked except for the typo.  Thanks.

Comment: This is interesting.  You can have one of the most sophisticated type-system around, a simple typo cannot be caught by it.

Comment: that's what warnings are for.

Comment: @gawi: It's not a bug, it's a feature! Although you get some warnings if you compile with `-Wall`.

Comment: I've added a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804484/in-haskell-why-non-exhaustive-patterns-are-not-compile-time-errors