# Extending algebraic data type

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Note: if this question is somehow odd, this is because I was only recently exposed to Haskell and am still adapting to the functional mindset.

Considering a data type like `Maybe`:

```
data MyOwnMaybe a = MyOwnNothing | MyOwnJust a
```

everyone using my data type will write functions like

```
maybeToList :: MyOwnMaybe a -> [a]
maybeToList MyOwnNothing  = []
maybeToList (MyOwnJust x) = [x]
```

Now, suppose that, at a later time, I wish to extend this data type

```
data MyOwnMaybe a = MyOwnNothing | MyOwnJust a | SuperpositionOfNothingAndJust a
```

how do I make sure that everyone's functions will break at compile-time?

Of course, there is the chance that somehow I'm not "getting" algebraic data types and maybe I shouldn't be doing this at all, but considering a data type `Action`

```
data Action = Reset | Send | Remove
```

it would seem that adding an extra `Action` like `Add` would not be so uncommon (and I wouldn't want to risk having all these functions around that possibly cannot handle my new `Action`)

Comment: Is your question really “make sure that everyone's functions _will_ break at compile-time”, or how to _prevent_ braking anyone's code? (Both can make sense)

Comment: seems like a slight variation of the [expression problem](http://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~laemmel/TheEagle/resources/pdf/xproblem1.pdf)

Comment: I think *both*. I really want to make sure that the program (both the part written by me, as the parts consuming my code) will function as it is supposed to. I feel like I'm running the risk of "falling through" a lot of these functions that were (obviously) not written with my new `Add` in mind. This "falling through" will cause, if I am correct, a runtime exception. This would be very undesirable.

Comment: How should code suddenly know how to  act "as it is supposed to" if you add *cases*?

Comment: In this case, I would prefer a compile-time error so that I know I need to reconsider these functions. This would be different from the case in which I have a

    maybeToList _  = []

at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, bad news first: sometimes you just can't do it. Period.

But that is language-agnostic; in any language you sometimes have to break interface. There is no way around it.

Now, good news: you can actually go a great length before you have to do that.

You just have to carefully consider what you export from your module. If, instead of exporting the internal workings of it, you export high-level functions, then there is a good chance you can rewrite those function using the new data type, and everything would go smooth.

In particular, be very careful when exporting data constructors. In this case, you don't just export functions that create your data; you are also exporting the possibility of pattern-matching; and that is not something that ties you pretty tight.

So, in your example, if you write functions like

```
myOwnNothing :: MyOwnMaybe a
myOwnJust :: a -> MyOwnMaybe a
```

and

```
fromMyOwnMaybe :: MyOwnMaybe a -> b -> (a -> b) -> b
fromMyOwnMaybe MyOwnNothing b _ = b
fromMyOwnMaybe (MyOwnJust a) _ f = f a
```

then it's reasonable to assume that you would be able to reimplement it for the updated `MyOwnMaybe` data type; so, just export those functions and the data type itself, but don't export constructors.

The only situation in which you would benefit from exporting constructors is when you are absolutely sure that your data type won't ever change. For example, `Bool` would always have only two (fully defined) values: `True` and `False`, it won't be extended by some `FileNotFound` or anything (although Edward Kmett might disagree). Ditto `Maybe` or `[]`.

But the idea is more general: stay as high-level as you can.

Comment: Would you generally advise to provide access to a data type of x cases with a function which takes x functions (some of which may be just a default value, like you did for MyOwnNothing) that provide access to these x different types?

Comment: That really depends on what the intended use is. I defined `fromMyOwnMaybe` assuming that `MyOwnMaybe` would serve almost the same purpose as the regular `Maybe`. Generally you would need to consider the intended use pattern — what do you know about it, what definitely should be there and what shouldn't. There is no predefined set of rules. If you don't know anything, then yes, this `fold`-like approach might be the best.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to know that GHC can warn about non-exhaustive pattern matches in function via the `-W` flag or explicitly with `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`.

There is a good discussion about why these warnings are not automatically compile-time errors at this SO question:

[In Haskell, why non-exhaustive patterns are not compile-time errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804484/in-haskell-why-non-exhaustive-patterns-are-not-compile-time-errors)

Also, consider this case where you have an ADT with a large number of constructors:

```
data Alphabet = A | B | C | ... | X | Y | Z

isVowel :: Alphabet -> Bool
isVowel A = True
isVowel E = True
isVowel I = True
isVowel O = True
isVowel U = True
isVowel _ = False
```

A default case is used as a convenience to avoid having to write out the other 21 cases.

Now if you add an addition constructor to `Alphabet`, should `isVowel` be flagged as "incomplete"?

Comment: I did not know this! Is there some way I can "mark" functions that *should* be complete (without a default case) and distinguish those from functions that will work regardless of whether we add new cases or not? (whether via `-W` or though some other means)

Comment: @WernerdeGroot Not in Haskell, AFAIK. I'd _really_ love to be able to ask the compiler to treat non exhaustiveness as an error. In some other languages e.g. Coq or Agda that is the case by default.

Comment: You can do it with `-Werror` but that's obviously a package deal.

Comment: @MasterMastic I find `-Werror` to be too radical, since it affects all the other warnings as well. That's an option, though. I'd like something which I could add to my .cabal without worrying about newer compilers being too picky in the future.

Comment: @chi, that makes good sense. Add `-ferror...` to `-fwarn...` and `-fno-warn...`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that a lot of modules do is *not to export* their constructors. Instead, they export functions that can be used (“smart constructors”). If you change your ADT later, you have to fix your functions in the module, but no one else's code gets broken.